# HECTOR SLAM, odometry in a low cost differential drive robot

Tags: slam, odometry, differential-drive

I'm a noob in robotics trying to evaluate requirements for a low cost differential drive indoor robot. Would highly appreciate comments on the following questions.

Given the inaccuracies in the wheel odometry (speed mismatch between motors, mismatch in wheel dimensions, unequal wear and tear of the two wheels with time and wheel slipping),

a) Is it fair to assume that a "Lidar (Ex: RPLIDAR A1M8 360 Degree 2D Laser Range Lidar) only" HECTOR SLAM solution will be good enough for an indoor robot? and should be the goto solution not needing wheel odometry.

b) Another doubt I have about the SLAM is let's say the robot has the environment MAP that it had crated earlier. Can it be cold started (switched ON) at any location within the MAP and it will be able to determine its position or does it have to always cold start from a "fixed point" in the MAP?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* amitjo, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: It really depends a lot on your robot, your environment, and your application.  Dead reckoning might be enough.  Or SLAM might not even be enough and further sensors are required.  It all depends.